# Is this possible with hashes in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash, attributes

```
class Card
  suit = {"C":"C", "D":"D", "H":"H", "S":"S"}
  rank = { :A => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 3, 4 => 4, 5 => 5, 6 => 6, 7 => 7, 8 => 8, 9 => 9, 10 => 10, :J => 11, :Q => 12, :K => 13}
end

card = Card.new

puts(card.rank["A"])
```

I have this code and I have a couple of questions.

Firstly, instead of doing `2 => 2`, why cant i just do `:2 : 2` or `2 : 2`
Secondly, what is the point of attributes if I cant access them like I have tried to above? Do i need to feed the attribute into a method and then call that method?

Comment: Note that `{"C":"C"}` is equivalent to `{C:"C"}`. BTW, what is the purpose of `suit`?

Comment: If you have two questions, you should ask two questions. But actually, you should post no questions, because both of your questions have been asked and answered multiple times already. The quick summary is: 1) Because the syntax doesn't allow it. 2) Because your `rank` hash doesn't have an `"A"` key, it only has an `:A` key, which is something completely different. Also, `suit` and `rank` are local variables in the class body, you cannot access them from outside (this is a third problem, one you didn't actually ask about; this has also been asked and answered many times already).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Firstly, instead of doing `2 => 2`, why cant i just do `:2 : 2` or `2 : 2`

`key: value` is a shortcut for `:key => value`, i.e. it treats `key` as a symbol.

`2: 2` doesn't work, because `:2` is not a valid symbol. You could use `'2': 2` instead, but it uses `:'2'` (a symbol) as the key, not `2` (a number).

However, symbols don't make much sense here, because you want to look up strings:

```
card.rank["A"] # <= "A" is not :A
```

> Secondly, what is the point of attributes if I cant access them like I have tried to above?

These are not attributes, but local variables. Attributes work like this:

```
class Card
  attr_reader :suit, :rank

  def initialize
    @suit = { 'C' => 'C', 'D' => 'D', 'H' => 'H', 'S' => 'S' }
    @rank = { 'A' => 1, '2' => 2, '3' => 3, '4' => 4, '5' => 5, '6' => 6, '7' => 7, '8' => 8, '9' => 9, '10' => 10, 'J' => 11, 'Q' => 12, 'K' => 13 }
  end
end

card = Card.new

card.rank      #=> {"A"=>1, "2"=>2, "3"=>3, "4"=>4, "5"=>5, "6"=>6, "7"=>7, "8"=>8, "9"=>9, "10"=>10, "J"=>11, "Q"=>12, "K"=>13}
card.rank['A'] #=> 1
```

It makes probably more sense to use constants:

```
class Card
  SUITS = { 'C' => 'C', 'D' => 'D', 'H' => 'H', 'S' => 'S' }
  RANKS = { 'A' => 1, '2' => 2, '3' => 3, '4' => 4, '5' => 5, '6' => 6, '7' => 7, '8' => 8, '9' => 9, '10' => 10, 'J' => 11, 'Q' => 12, 'K' => 13 }
end

Card::RANKS['A'] #=> 1
```

And use attributes for the suit and rank of a specific card:

```
class Card
  SUITS = { 'C' => 'C', 'D' => 'D', 'H' => 'H', 'S' => 'S' }
  RANKS = { 'A' => 1, '2' => 2, '3' => 3, '4' => 4, '5' => 5, '6' => 6, '7' => 7, '8' => 8, '9' => 9, '10' => 10, 'J' => 11, 'Q' => 12, 'K' => 13 }

  attr_reader :suit, :rank

  def initialize(suit, rank)
    @suit = suit
    @rank = rank
  end

  def value
    RANKS[rank]
  end
end

card = Card.new('C', 'A')

card.suit    #=> "C"
card.rank    #=> "A"
card.value   #=> 1
```

Comment: this seems to work. only problem when i run it is that nothing happens?

Comment: It's a common practice to write the results of an expression as a comment on the same line (or the next line). This resembles the way IRB works. If you want to generate actual output, you have to use `puts`, e.g. `puts card.suit`

Comment: of course. gonna put that down to Friday morning syndrome. cheers!